# In log4j-config.xsd there is no targetNamespace. So how can we do maven validdation of log4j2.xml without targetNmaespace?

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, xsd-validation

In log4j-config.xsd there is no targetNamespace. So how can we do maven validdation of log4j2.xml without targetNmaespace?

As in log4j2.xml i want to give schemaLocation.

My xml looks like :

```
<Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config https://arm.rnd.ki.sw.xxxx.se/artifactory/proj-switching-jcat-seki-release-local/se/ericsson/jcat/ebs/log4j/Log4j-config.xsd">
.....   
</Configuration>
```

And xsd looks like:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
......
</xs:schema>
```

PS: I cant add "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/config" in xsd as targetNamespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the issue is resoleve.
I have added targetNamespace in github repo.

https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/resources/Log4j-config.xsd